# Java Hibernate Entities not joined correctly (bidirectional)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two `Java` `Hibernate` entities with `oneToMany` relation. Also I have `Spring` controller and `AngularJS` on front-end. When I try `/cars/getCars` on `Chrome` browser, I get network status failed. And Eclipse stop work (freeze).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="auto")
public class Make {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(length = 100)
  private String make;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "make")
  private List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>(0);

  public String getMake() {
    return make;
  }

  ...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="models")
public class Model {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @Column(length = 100)
  private String model;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_maker") 
  private Make make;

  public Model() {}

  public void setModel(String model){
    this.model = model;
  }
  ...
```

DAO

```
public List<Make> getCars(){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Make.class);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

and `Spring` controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/cars/getCars")
 public @ResponseBody List<Make> getCars(){
     DAO d = new DAO();
     return d.getCars();
 }
```

For me looks like n+1 query problem.

And fragment from exception :

```
..at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ...
```

And if change : `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "make") to @OneToMany` an remove `make` field from `Model` class than start work normal but now I cant get `make` by `model`.

Comment: How did you try to debug this so far? How do you know that this is a Hibernate issue? What do you mean by Eclipse stops working? Why do you think it is an n+1 query problem? Have you tried to stop doing lazy fetch when you clearly want to return with the full resultset of cars? Where is the DAO code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems related to json parsing with hibernate bidirectional relationships.

You need to add @JsonIgnoreProperties after your @ManyToOne, this annotation is from jackson 2.
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="auto")
public class Make {
  ...

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "make")
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "make") // to ignore the make from Model class while parsing to your json/xml
  private List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>(0);

  ...
}
```

Similarly,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_maker") 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "models") // to ignore the models from Make class while parsing to your json/xml
private Make make;
```

This type of approach worked for me in @ManyToMany, hope will help you.

Comment: Worked like a charm- I had the same issue with a bi-directional OneToMany relationship;  this was the first time I discovered that ignoreProperties could be applied at the property level :). Thanks very much!! Is there a decent documentation link for this  sort of deeper features of fasterxml?

Comment: I am also looking for documentation for the same.
But you can get some good examples on mkyong.com